# Posted tweet doesn't show on Twitter timeline

Tags: android, twitter

I am using an edit text box and a post button to post tweets on Twitter's timeline using my app.

But after all the processing the "status updated successfully" toast appears, but the tweet is not showing on the timeline... It gives error 400 in [LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file) and shows a message about bad authentication data!! I am new to [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). How can I fix this problem?

Here is the code:

```
    public class PostCommentActivity extends Activity {

        private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "*****";
        private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "*******";
        static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
        static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
        static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
        static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        EditText et;
        Button postbtn;
        Twitter twitter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.post_comment);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

            mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",
                                 0);
            postbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Post_btn);
            postbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Get the status from EditText
                Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
                String status = et.getText().toString();

                // Check for blank text
                if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                    // update status
                    new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
                }
                else {
                    // EditText is empty
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please enter status message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PostCommentActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting Places JSON
         *
         **/
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
            String status = args[0];
            try {
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);

                ;    // Access Token
                String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                        PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");

                // Access Token Secret
                String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(
                                               PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");
                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token,
                access_token_secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build())
                                        .getInstance(accessToken);
                twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

                // Update status
                twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);
                Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
            }
            catch (TwitterException e) {
                // Error in updating status
                Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            // Dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();

            // Updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // Clearing EditText field
                    et.setText("");
                }
             });
        }}
    }
```

Comment: you have hardcoded the toast in your postexecute. This doesn't guarantee that tweet was successful. See if you get any exception which you have catched in doInbackground method

Comment: it gives this logcat result

08-26 03:09:46.631: D/Twitter Update Error(2899): 400:The request was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain why. This is the status code will be returned during version 1.0 rate limiting(https://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting). In API v1.1, a request without authentication is considered invalid and you will get this response.
 D/Twitter Update Error(2899): message - Bad Authentication data
 D/Twitter Update Error(2899): code - 215

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution... Try this code:

```
public class PostCommentActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "***";
    private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "******";

    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    EditText et;
    Button postbtn;
    RequestToken requestToken;
    Twitter twitter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setContentView(R.layout.post_comment);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",
                             0);

        postbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Post_btn);
        postbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String token = "*****";
                String secret = "*****";
                AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
                twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
                String status = et.getText().toString();
                if ((status.trim().length() > 0)) {
                    try {
                        twitter.updateStatus(status);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Clearing EditText field
                        et.setText("");
                    }
                    catch (TwitterException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // EditText is empty
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter status message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```